# Spring Boot 1.5.2 - Cannot find Bean due to " Cannot search for matching files underneath URL "?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.2 and it has this annoying error which I could not understand the reason.

I have a Main class with these scanning configured:

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.abc", "org.abc"})
    @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.abc", "org.abc", "abc"}) 
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc", "org.abc", "abc"})
    public class ApplicationMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
         ....
    }
```

A model class

```
  File: AbcUser.java
  package com.abc.admin.model

  @Entity
  @Table(name = AbcUser.TABLE_NAME)
  public class AbcUser {
  }
```

And an interface class which extends `CrudRepository`:

```
   File UserRespository.java inside this package.

   package com.abc.repository.interfaces

   @Repository
   public interface UserRespository extends CrudRepository<AbcUser, Long> {
    
    @Transactional
    Long deleteByUsername(String username);
  }
```

Now, when I tried to start the web application, it first has the warning which says, it cannot scand files...And then throws error, that the **Bean** cannot be found.

```
       java -jar abc.war


        WARN: Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [war:file:/home//tmp/build/applications/petascope/petascope_main/target/abc.war*/WEB-INF/classes/org/abc/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [war:file:/home//tmp/build/applications/petascope/petascope_main/target/abc.war*/WEB-INF/classes/org/abc/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: war:file:/home//tmp/build/applications/petascope/petascope_main/target/abc.war*/WEB-INF/classes/org/abc/
        at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:218)
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:213)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:685)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:477)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:279)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.buildDefaultPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:525)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.readPersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:505)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:442)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:426)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:325)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at org.abc.MigrationBeanApplicationConfiguration.createEntityManagerFactory(MigrationBeanApplicationConfiguration.java:313)
```

Due to it cannot create **Bean**

```
    ERROR [2021-08-23 16:32:17] TomcatStarter@63: Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'requestsFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepositoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepositoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRespository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.rasdaman.admin.model.RasdamanUser
  WARN [2021-08-23 16:32:17] AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@550: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
 ERROR [2021-08-23 16:32:17] SpringApplication@815: Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRespository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.abc.admin.model.AbcUser
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the scanning problem which leads to the error of Bean not found from https://shekerama.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/how-to-solve-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-not-an-managed-type/.

```
final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.abc", "org.abc");
```